# External IP to docker Gitlab on WIndow 10

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab

I have windows 10 machine, i have docker installed on it. I want to configure a gitlab image on docker. I pulled the gitlab image from docker hub. I want to give external IP address to the docker image, however when i am getting following error:

> Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint gitlabtest
>   (d1c581b075e96c7cbae08583adc76348c170919a8c6aa2197d6b52ce44232e72):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.xx.x.81:8080: bind: The
>   requested address is not valid in its context.

Not sure what i am missing. Can anyone please help

```
docker run --detach  --hostname gitlab.example.com 
--publish 192.xxx.0.81:8080:80 --publish 192.xxx.x.81:22:22 
--env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://192.xxx.0.81:8080'; 
gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true; gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port']=22;" 
--name gitlabtest --restart always --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab 
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Comment: I assume that 192.xxx.x.81 is your actual address. Do you have multiple interfaces on that machine?

Comment: Yes, it a actual address. Basically i need to expose this docker-gitlab outside my domain.

Comment: do you have multiple interfaces on that machine?

Comment: No.Also i want to know, where are the repository files stored on host machine. I am using windows 10 machine and in the Dockers i have created a Gitlab image. I also mounted a local volume. I want to know whether the repository files can be stored in host machine and also can i move those file to another repo in case my docker image does not run for some reason. Sorry, i am asking lot of question, but i am very new to docker and gitlab, so please bare with my questions.